SqlBulkoperations isn't adding records to ms access database. With mysql to code seems to work
I need to use SqlBulkoperations to add a little more than 400k records to an MSAccess database (mdb). Because I couldn't get it to work, I have taken the example provided by Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbulkoperations-function?view=sql-server-ver16) and put it in a command line program. With minimal changes to the code it works with an Mysql database. Trying the same with an MSAccess database doesn't result in any errors, but no records get added to the table. The changes I made are marked with //eusch.
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

// SQLBulkOperations_Function.cpp  
// compile with: ODBC32.lib  
#include <windows.h>  
#include <sqlext.h>  
#include "stdio.h"  

void test_odbc_bulk() {  
   retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);  
   retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);   
  
   retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc);   
   retcode = SQLSetConnectAttr(hdbc, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)5, 0);  
  
   retcode = SQLConnect(hdbc, (SQLCHAR*) "Northwind", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*) NULL, 0, NULL, 0);  
   retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt);  
  
   // Set the following statement attributes:  
   // SQL_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE:           Keyset-driven  
   // SQL_ATTR_ROW_BIND_TYPE:         Row-wise  
   // SQL_ATTR_ROW_ARRAY_SIZE:        10  
   // SQL_ATTR_USE_BOOKMARKS:         Use variable-length bookmarks  
   // SQL_ATTR_ROW_STATUS_PTR:        Points to RowStatusArray  
   // SQL_ATTR_ROW_BIND_OFFSET_PTR:   Points to BindOffset  
   retcode = SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_CURSOR_KEYSET_DRIVEN, 0);  
   retcode = SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROW_BIND_TYPE, (SQLPOINTER)sizeof(CustStruct), 0);  
   retcode = SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROW_ARRAY_SIZE, (SQLPOINTER)10, 0);  
   retcode = SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_USE_BOOKMARKS, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_UB_VARIABLE, 0);  
   retcode = SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROW_STATUS_PTR, RowStatusArray, 0);  
   retcode = SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROW_BIND_OFFSET_PTR, &BindOffset, 0);  
  
SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_CONCURRENCY, (SQLPOINTER) SQL_CONCUR_VALUES, 0);//eusch added this one

   // Bind arrays to the bookmark, CustomerID, CompanyName, Address, and Phone columns.  
   retcode = SQLBindCol(hstmt, 0, SQL_C_VARBOOKMARK, CustArray[0].Bookmark, sizeof(CustArray[0].Bookmark), &CustArray[0].BookmarkLen);  
   retcode = SQLBindCol(hstmt, 1, SQL_C_ULONG, &CustArray[0].CustomerID, 0, &CustArray[0].CustIDInd);  
   retcode = SQLBindCol(hstmt, 2, SQL_C_CHAR, CustArray[0].CompanyName, sizeof(CustArray[0].CompanyName), &CustArray[0].NameLenOrInd);  
   retcode = SQLBindCol(hstmt, 3, SQL_C_CHAR, CustArray[0].Address, sizeof(CustArray[0].Address), &CustArray[0].AddressLenOrInd);  
   retcode = SQLBindCol(hstmt, 4, SQL_C_CHAR, CustArray[0].Phone, sizeof(CustArray[0].Phone), &CustArray[0].PhoneLenOrInd);  
  
   // Execute a statement to retrieve rows from the Customers table.  
   retcode = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)"SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, Address, Phone FROM Customers", SQL_NTS);  
   // Fetch and display the first 10 rows.  

   retcode = SQLFetchScroll(hstmt, SQL_FETCH_NEXT, 0);  
   // DisplayCustData(CustArray, 10);  
  
   // Call GetAction to get an action and a row number from the user.  
   // while (GetAction(&Action, &RowNum)) {  
   Action = SEND_TO_DATA_SOURCE;  //eusch changed to action to SEND_TO_DATA_SOURCE
   RowNum = 2;  
   switch (Action) {  
      case SQL_FETCH_NEXT:  
      case SQL_FETCH_PRIOR:  
      case SQL_FETCH_FIRST:  
      case SQL_FETCH_LAST:  
      case SQL_FETCH_ABSOLUTE:  
      case SQL_FETCH_RELATIVE:  
         // Fetch and display the requested data.  
         SQLFetchScroll(hstmt, Action, RowNum);  
         // DisplayCustData(CustArray, 10);  
         break;  
  
      case UPDATE_ROW:  
         // Check if we have reached the maximum number of buffered updates.  
         if (NumUpdates < 10) {  
            // Get the new customer data and place it in the next available element of  
            // the buffered updates section of CustArray, copy the bookmark of the row  
            // being updated to the same element, and increment the update counter.  
            // Checking to see we have not already buffered an update for this  
            // row not shown.  
            // GetNewCustData(CustArray, UPDATE_OFFSET + NumUpdates);  
            memcpy(CustArray[UPDATE_OFFSET + NumUpdates].Bookmark,  
               CustArray[RowNum - 1].Bookmark,  
               CustArray[RowNum - 1].BookmarkLen);  
            CustArray[UPDATE_OFFSET + NumUpdates].BookmarkLen =  
               CustArray[RowNum - 1].BookmarkLen;  
            NumUpdates++;  
         } else {  
            printf("Buffers full. Send buffered changes to the data source.");  
         }  
         break;  
      case DELETE_ROW:  
         // Check if we have reached the maximum number of buffered deletes.  
         if (NumDeletes < 10) {  
            // Copy the bookmark of the row being deleted to the next available element  
            // of the buffered deletes section of CustArray and increment the delete  
            // counter. Checking to see we have not already buffered an update for  
            // this row not shown.  
            memcpy(CustArray[DELETE_OFFSET + NumDeletes].Bookmark,  
               CustArray[RowNum - 1].Bookmark,  
               CustArray[RowNum - 1].BookmarkLen);  
  
            CustArray[DELETE_OFFSET + NumDeletes].BookmarkLen =  
               CustArray[RowNum - 1].BookmarkLen;  
  
            NumDeletes++;  
         } else  
            printf("Buffers full. Send buffered changes to the data source.");  
         break;  
  
      case ADD_ROW:  
         // reached maximum number of buffered inserts?  
         if (NumInserts < 10) {  
            // Get the new customer data and place it in the next available element of  
            // the buffered inserts section of CustArray and increment insert counter.  
            // GetNewCustData(CustArray, INSERT_OFFSET + NumInserts);  
            NumInserts++;  
         } else  
            printf("Buffers full. Send buffered changes to the data source.");  
         break;  
  
      case SEND_TO_DATA_SOURCE:  
         // If there are any buffered updates, inserts, or deletes, set the array size  
         // to that number, set the binding offset to use the data in the buffered  
         // update, insert, or delete part of CustArray, and call SQLBulkOperations to  
         // do the updates, inserts, or deletes. Because we will never have more than  
         // 10 updates, inserts, or deletes, we can use the same row status array.  
         if (NumUpdates) {  
            SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROW_ARRAY_SIZE, (SQLPOINTER)NumUpdates, 0);  
            BindOffset = UPDATE_OFFSET * sizeof(CustStruct);  
            SQLBulkOperations(hstmt, SQL_UPDATE_BY_BOOKMARK);  
            NumUpdates = 0;  
         }  
  
         if (NumInserts) {  
            SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROW_ARRAY_SIZE, (SQLPOINTER)NumInserts, 0);  
            BindOffset = INSERT_OFFSET * sizeof(CustStruct);  
           retcode= SQLBulkOperations(hstmt, SQL_ADD);  
DISPLAY_DEBUG(retcode,SQL_HANDLE_STMT,hstmt); //eusch added this one
            NumInserts = 0;  
         }  
  
         if (NumDeletes) {  
            SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROW_ARRAY_SIZE, (SQLPOINTER)NumDeletes, 0);  
            BindOffset = DELETE_OFFSET * sizeof(CustStruct);  
            SQLBulkOperations(hstmt, SQL_DELETE_BY_BOOKMARK);  
            NumDeletes = 0;  
         }  
  
         // If there were any updates, inserts, or deletes, reset the binding offset  
         // and array size to their original values.  
         if (NumUpdates || NumInserts || NumDeletes) {  
            SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROW_ARRAY_SIZE, (SQLPOINTER)10, 0);  
            BindOffset = 0;  
         }  
         break;  
   }  
   // }  
  
   // Close the cursor.  
   SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_CLOSE);  
}

The code to fill the data structures is:
#define _strcpy( _a , _b )  strcpy( (char *)_a , _b )

void
fill_test_data()
{
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
    {
        CustArray[ i+INSERT_OFFSET ].CustomerID = 1 + i ;
        _strcpy( CustArray[ i+INSERT_OFFSET ].CompanyName , "test" );  
        _strcpy( CustArray[ i+INSERT_OFFSET ].Address , "test" );  
        _strcpy( CustArray[ i+INSERT_OFFSET ].Phone , "test" );  

        CustArray[ i+INSERT_OFFSET ].CustIDInd = sizeof( CustArray[ i+INSERT_OFFSET ].CustomerID ) ;
        CustArray[ i+INSERT_OFFSET ].NameLenOrInd =
        CustArray[ i+INSERT_OFFSET ].AddressLenOrInd =
        CustArray[ i+INSERT_OFFSET ].PhoneLenOrInd =  SQL_NTS ;
    }

    NumInserts = 10 ;
}

Further I added some debugging functionality:
#define DISPLAY_DEBUG( status , type , stmt )   \
\
    if( status != SQL_SUCCESS ) display_debug( type , stmt )

static void
display_debug( SQLSMALLINT handle_type , SQLHANDLE handle )
{
    SQLCHAR     state[ SQL_SQLSTATE_SIZE + 1 ]  ;
    SQLINTEGER  native              ;
    SQLSMALLINT length              ;
    SQLRETURN   status              ;
    int     i               ;
    SQLCHAR     text[ 256 ]         ;
    
    for( i = 1 ; TRUE ; i++ )
    {
        status = SQLGetDiagRecA( handle_type ,
                     handle ,
                     i ,
                     state ,
                     &native ,
                     text  ,
                     sizeof( text ) ,
                     &length ) ;
                    
        if( status != SQL_SUCCESS )
        {
            break ;
        }
        
        fprintf( stderr , "%s %s\n" , state , text ) ;
    }

}


Have you tried using a linked table, and then a append or make table query?

Do you mean a table in an access database (mdb) linked to an mysql database?

Yes. You can then create a append query in Access (or a make table), and try that for the transfer. The nice part is no VBA code is required at all. However, with that number of records, Access can sometimes hang up on you. And you find this approach does run rather fast.  So, this idea is worth a try.

Eventually te data needs to be stored in a ms access table. So don't see how it would help.

Of course it will help, since we are using Access to pull data from the linked table to a local Access table. See my post below for how this works.

I think there is a misunderstanding. The original data does not come from a Mysql database but from a text file. This text file contains 400k records and must be stored in the MS Access database. When you do this with insert statement, the whole operation takes way too long. I hope that SqlBulkoperations() will shorten the time considerably. However, I could not get my code to work. That is why I wrote a separate program that uses the example from the Microsoft documentation. The example code also does not work with an Access database. It does work with a Mysql database.

So, in comments, I am suggesting you create a linked table to MySQL.
Once done, then you can with ease take that linked table, and convert to a local table.
There are two ways to do this.
You can create a new query, and choose make table query.
Hence this:

So, create a new query, select you linked table as per above.
Now simply right click anywhere in the query builder, and change the query type to a "make table". You  will be prompted for the local table to create.
Hence this:

So, now enter the local table you want to create in Access.
At this point then, you can select the columns you want (or even "*" for all columns). (just double click on the * to place it in the grid below).
Now, just run the query, and it will pull the data from the server into the local table.
The above is a great approach if you have to frequently pull the table from the MySQL database.
However, you can also just right click on the linked table, and choose "convert to local table". This "one step" approach quite much does all of the above for you, but then you lose the linked table - and during testing, you may well not want that.
Hence, you can do this in place of above:

Either way, the above allows you to pull data from the server to a local table, takes less then 1 minute of your time, and bonus points is that you don't have to write one line of code at all.
So, create a linked table, make sure it can open and works. Now close that table, and try either of the above 2 approaches (make table query, or simply right click and choose "convert to local table"). Both approaches require a valid working linked table to have been created.

Thanks. I think there is a misunderstanding. The original data does not come from a Mysql database but from a text file. This text file contains 400k records and must be stored in the MS Access database. When you do this with insert statement, the whole operation takes way too long. I hope that SqlBulkoperations() will shorten the time considerably. However, I could not get my code to work. That is why I wrote a separate program that uses the example from the Microsoft documentation. The example code also does not work with an Access database. It does work with a Mysql database.

Ah, then you JUST using Access, which is part of office, you know, word, power-point etc. Why not then just use the built in Access import wizard. Why would you think your code going to make the disk drive all of a sudden run faster? The built in import wizard in Access does not use ODBC, and thus introduction of a whole new software stack such as ODBC is most certainly NOT going to run ANY faster then the built-in native file based import wizard that does not use ODBC at all. The internal Access import routines are 100% file based, and as such, your not processing limited.

There is simply NO WAY your code and introduction of the ODBC stack is going to run faster then the built in native "file based" import routines inside of Access.  So, if you using the Access import wizards, the disk drive and file system "out of the blue" is not all of a sudden going to work faster, or "speed up" the disk drive.  Hence, the built-in import wizard not processing limited, but really only limited by the file system speeds, and processing not the issue, and some custom routine that introduces ODBC software stack will for sure run slower then the native import routines in Access

In other words, if you now using the import wizards in Access, then is is VERY unlikely that introduction of a whole new software stack (ODBC) is going to speed things up, and if anything, that will slow things down.  It's not clear how fast the native import routines run, but they by-pass and don't use ODBC, and hence it is unreasonable to suggest, hint or think that such code will run faster then the internal native code inside of Access which is file based, and not ODBC based.

Keep in mind the native built in "file based" routines should import 400,000 rows in less then 10 seconds. I on a low cost laptop can import a text (csv) file of 150,000 rows in about 2 seconds of time, and hence 400,000 rows will not take much longer. (say, 4-5 seconds, and certainly under 10 seconds of time).

and keep in mind the fact that SQL bulk operations work with say SQL server? Gooly, power-point, Excel and Ms-Access are file based systems - nothing at all to do with SQL server, or MySQL.  While the ODBC spec does support SQL bulk operations, the native file read + writing built into Access does not really benifit or use bulk operations, since ODBC is not required to use Access files. Best to use native file based operations when using Access, since it not a server based data engine, but only some software that reads and writes files on the disk drive - much like how Word or power-point does

The user of the application doesn't have ms access on their system. The existing application is using odbc to connect to an ms access database. The application needs the extra functionality of storing 400k records into the database.

Ok, but attempting to use code for SQL server is VERY unlikely going to work for ms-access, and the ms-access (unlike SQL server or MySQL) does not support  multiple SQL statements (including insert) being sent to the data engine - the data engine thus can't really consume a bulk SQL insert statement - you have to do one line (sql statement) at a time, and that VERY much suggests you use the DAO object model. Or you drop the bulk inserts - they don't work with the JET (or now newer ACE) data engine. Near zero surprise that bulk inserts don't work with a file based database.

If you call SQLGetFunctions(hdbc, SQL_API_SQLBULKOPERATIONS, &supported) ;  it shows that SqlBulkoperations() is supported by de ms access odbc driver. So I'm not sure why I am attempting to use code for SQL server.

Fair enough, keep in mind that bulk operations are done to speed things up "mostly" in regards to server based engines, since they have a HUGE boatload of extra moving parts like starting a transaction, and all kinds of extra things before data can start to "flow", this startup is much like a helicopter taking off - quite a lot occurs before table writing can start and get up to speed - once all those handstands are done, then data can start to flow and be written. With JET, this is not all that much of a huge deal. But, fair is fair, and JET + ODBC does look to support bulk operations.

However, and if I have time, I think speed and ease of code would be to adopt + use the DAO data engine, and add via reocrdset - it tends to be faster in this use case. I'll try to post a working c++ example later today if time permits. And, any chance you can use managed code, such as c#, or are  you committed to c++?

I'm commited to C++
